# android volley library "Error:(9, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'"

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to use android volley in my app. But it says "Error:(9, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'"
I tried to upgrade the plugin but that link doesn't work. I'v added a scre
https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

[image: Android volley error]

Comment: Show us both of your build.gradle files please

Comment: post your `gradle` and `appModule`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **`UPDATE`** your ***gradle-plugin*** **`VERSION`**. Then **`SYNC`** with **INTERNET**.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

}
```

And set this version

```
   compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```